# Iridium 9603 does not send the location that I supply

Tags: at-command, iridium

I'm trying to send my location in Iridium 9603 AT+SBDIX command (different from satellite location which is not accurate), but the location sent is still the satellite one.
Is there a limitation in 9603 to send optional location in +SBDIX command?
**EDIT**
Response examples:
Good response:
+SBDIX: 0, 1363, 0, 0, 0, 0

OK

Bad response:
AT+SBDIX=+3267.979,+034141.947

ERROR
(This is because the longitude has extra digit)
I think the location is wrong because the location that I receive (in other app) is not what I expect to get (on a map).

Comment: I'm not an expert on your device. I download the AT guide but I cannot perform any direct test. That said, could you update your question with the `+SBDIX` command response? How do you know that the sent location is wrong? Maybe you receive some unsolicited messages? If yes, could you post them?

Comment: Roberto, you can see my edit. I'm not getting location unsolicited message. I'm getting other unsolicited messages, like SBDRING or CIEV.